# matlab coding - finding shortest path problem

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, matlab, trees, recursive-algorithms

Lately I've been trying to learn MATLAB and there's this project that have been assigned to me which I'm trying to do. the description of the project is as follows:
we have a set of 100 points: $${(0,0),(0,1)....(0,10),...(1,0),(1,1)....,(1,0),...,(10,10)}$$
1-choose 10 random points and color them red , those are points we can not go to.(others shall be green).
2-take point (0,0) as the start and color it blue
3-randomly choose the end point and color it black
then the assignment asks us to find the shortest path from the start point to the end one (and to graph it).
so I plotted the dots in the following code:

```
clc;clear;close all
all_dots=zeros(10,10);
red_dots_x=zeros(1,10);
red_dots_y=zeros(1,10);
for counter=1:10
    all_dots(randperm(10,10),randperm(10,10))=1;
    red_dots_x=randi(10,1,10);
    red_dots_y=randi(10,1,10);
end 
for counter2=1:10
        all_dots(red_dots_x(counter2),red_dots_y(counter2))=2;           
end
all_dots(1,1)=3; 
x1=randi([2,10]);
y1=randi([2,10]);
all_dots(randi(10),randi(10))=4;
for i=1:10
    for j=1:10
        if all_dots(i,j)==1
            figure(1);plot(i,j,'og','MarkerFaceColor','g');hold on;
        else if all_dots(i,j)==2
            figure(1);plot(i,j,'or','MarkerFaceColor','r');hold on;
        else if all_dots(i,j)==3
            figure(1);plot(i,j,'ob','MarkerFaceColor','b');hold on;
        else if all_dots(i,j)==4
            figure(1);plot(i,j,'ok','MarkerFaceColor','k');hold on;
            end
            end
            end
        end
    end
     xlim([0,11]);ylim([0,11]);
end
```

[image]
now I have to get on finding the shortest path. after a lot of search I found two algorithms that can be useful for my intention:

1-[BFS](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.bfsearch.html)

2-Dijkstra (setting all the weights as 1)

and again after reading on the [MATHWORKS](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.shortestpath.html) website I found out there are built-in functions for those algorithms. but the problem is I PREFER not to use those built-ins because the course coach haven't taught them (so I may not get the full point) and also I neither have an source-destination set nor the adjacency matrix required for using those functions.
literally ANY kind of help even for the code I have already written is very much appreciated.

p.s: I am allowed to move diagonaly, vertically and horizontally and all distances (even the diagonal distance) between points are the same.

Comment: @JeanMarie thanks, edited.

Comment: Why don't you attempt at first one of the 2 "L-shaped" paths connecting start and end-points and check whether or not there is a red point on them ? The probability that it works is maybe 30% ! Then, if there is a red point, see whether you can go around it by testing its vicinity, etc...

Comment: @JeanMarie well that path might be the path with least turns (that is actually what the second part of the project wants) but for now I'm just looking for the shortest way.

Comment: Are you allowed to move diagonally? In most cases a straight line from, let's say (0,0) to (5,3) will not intersect with any point, nevertheless any red point.

Comment: @Laray yes I am but there is no guarantee for what you said since the red dots are placed randomly.

Comment: Otherwise consider "geodesic distance" propagation from the start point.

Comment: @JeanMarie any reference for reading about it?

Comment: Here is one: https://www.academia.edu/20352630/Fast_and_accurate_geodesic_distance_transform_by_ordered_propagation

Comment: @infinite, I know, but it happens very rarely and is easy to check. A slight variation of the diagonal might be the optimal path in that case (i.e move one space up, then diagonally across)

Comment: @Laray thanks I will consider that method too.

Comment: With your post scriptum (allowing diagonal moves) it is not the same problem (The "L" moves aren't minimal...)

Answer (score 0):

So after a lot of search a CS student helped me solve the problem. this is the algorithm:

1-from any point (initially the start point) find all the adjacent points and list them.

2-from the list delete the unavailable points (red ones).

3-for all available points find the euclidean distance from the end point.

4-choose the available adjacent point in which you will have the least distance from the end point.

5-while you haven't reached the end point repeat the loop.

it was really fascinating for me that non of the BFS,DFS or Dijkstra algorithms were needed for this problem.
for further use I will put the code for this project.

```
clc;clear;close all
all_dots=zeros(10,10);
red_dots_x=zeros(1,10);
red_dots_y=zeros(1,10);
for counter=1:10
    all_dots(randperm(10,10),randperm(10,10))=1;
    red_dots_x=randi(10,1,10);
    red_dots_y=randi(10,1,10);
end 
for counter2=1:10
        all_dots(red_dots_x(counter2),red_dots_y(counter2))=2;           
end
all_dots(1,1)=3; 
x1=randi([2,10]);
y1=randi([2,10]);
rand1=randi(10);
rand2=randi(10);
all_dots(rand1,rand2)=4;
for i=1:10
    for j=1:10
        if all_dots(i,j)==1
            figure(1);plot(i,j,'og','MarkerFaceColor','g','MarkerSize',15,'MarkerEdgeColor','b');hold on;
        else if all_dots(i,j)==2
            figure(1);plot(i,j,'or','MarkerFaceColor','r','MarkerSize',15,'MarkerEdgeColor',[107 76 154]./255);hold on;
        else if all_dots(i,j)==3
            figure(1);plot(i,j,'ob','MarkerFaceColor','b','MarkerSize',15);hold on;
        else if all_dots(i,j)==4
            figure(1);plot(i,j,'ok','MarkerFaceColor','k','MarkerSize',15);hold on;
            end
            end
            end
        end
    end
     xlim([0,11]);ylim([0,11]);
end
dot=[1,1];
counter100=1;
while dot(1)~=rand1 || dot(2)~=rand2
    steper(counter100,:)=dot;
    dots=[dot(1)+1,dot(2);dot(1),dot(2)+1;dot(1)-1,dot(2);dot(1),dot(2)-1;dot(1)+1,dot(2)+1;dot(1)+1,dot(2)-1;dot(1)-1,dot(2)+1];
    for i=1:7
            if dots(i,1)>=1 && dots(i,2)>=1 && all_dots(dots(i,1),dots(i,2))~=2
                availdots(i,:)=dots(i,:);
            end
    end
    sizea=size(availdots);
        for i=1:sizea(1,1)
                distances(i)=hypot(availdots(i,1)-rand1,availdots(i,2)-rand2);
        end
        [m,next]=min(distances);
        dot=availdots(next,:);
        counter100=counter100+1; 
end
sth=size(steper);
steper(sth(1,1)+1,:)=[rand1,rand2];
plot(steper(:,1),steper(:,2),'k','LineWidth',8);
```

P.S:I will still very much appreciate any explanation about the way this method is working.